# Trying to get property of non object Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The error occurs when i print the messages for the logged in user sent by others to him. I did var_dump in my controller as well as in my view. I also did `{{$threads->count()}}` in my view and it showed 27(thread count). But when i access the view file it throws me the above mentioned error.

Here is my controller code

```
public function index()
{
    $currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;
    $threads = Thread::getAllLatest()->get();
    return view('chatindex', compact('threads', 'currentUserId'));
}
```

I also printed the `currentUserId` in  view and it also works fine

Here is my view code (where the error occurs)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   @if (Session::has('error_message'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {!! Session::get('error_message') !!}
        </div>
    @endif
    @if($threads->count() > 0)
        @foreach($threads as $thread)
        <?php $class = $thread->isUnread($currentUserId) ? 'alert-info' : ''; ?>
        <div class="media alert {!!$class!!}">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{!! link_to('messages/' . $thread->id, $thread->subject) !!}</h4>
            <p>{!! $thread->latestMessage->body !!}</p>
            <p><small><strong>Creator:</strong> {!! $thread->creator()->name !!}</small></p>
            <p><small><strong>Participants:</strong> {!! $thread->participantsString(Auth::id()) !!}</small></p>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>Sorry, no threads.</p>
    @endif
@stop
```

It throws me the error Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-projects\user_prof\resources\views\chatindex.blade.php)

Comment: Can you provide `$threads` collection listing and number of line where error occurs?

Comment: What about `$thread->latestMessage` is that an object ?!

Comment: The error is probably here `$thread->creator()->name`. Show us how you create that relationship in your Model pelase.

Comment: I am using a messenger package from github , The error is on the line 13    <h4 class="media-heading">{!! link_to('messages/' . $thread->id, $thread->subject) !!}</h4> , and i tried to remove the next three lines and ran it. it doesn't throw any error. but after that the error again occurs when i added the removed lines back

Comment: Hi try `$thread->creator->name` its common call for related model

Comment: The strange part is the code i have posted with the question works well in another computer and throws the error in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your foreach **$thread** is an array() so use it like one as

```
 $thread['id'], $thread['subject']
```

Comment: The strange part is the code i have posted with the question works well in another computer and throws the error in my computer.